# How to cache inbound responses to outgoing requests in node.js, based on cache-control?

Tags: node.js, caching, http-headers

In our node.js app, we make http requests to other services for data needed to fullfill incoming requests.

E.g. when we identify the organisation of an authenticated user, we call out to the organisation service for details we need.

To increase performance, we would like to cache the responses to these outgoing requests. However, the libraries identified thus far all have statically configured TTL in the client. We want our cached to be controlled by the Cache-control and Expires  headers received with the response.

Any good caching libraries out there that handle this type of thing?